# List of arrays: How to plot elements of each array(Python 2.7)?

Tags: python, arrays, list, plot

It's hard to describe the problem I'm facing.

I have a list of arrays that looks like:

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1']... etc`

I'd like to plot d vs e for each element.

The way I'm trying (which I know is wrong, but I just don't know what the right way is) is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
for i in list:
    pl.plot(list[i][3],list[i][4])
```

So, I'm trying to get the 3rd element of all arrays in the list, and plot them against the 4th element.

Edit: I've also tried:

```
for i in list:
    x.append(list[3])
    y.append(list[4])
```

to obtain arrays for x (an array of all of the 3rd elements) and y (all the 4th elements), but this isn't right either - x is just an array of the 3rd element in the list repeated 60 or so times. I want the third element of each array in the list in sequence.

Comment: As I known, you can't plot strings but you can put a label and text.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "plot".  It seems that you're trying to pull out strings and plot them, so what do you want a plot of, for example, `"d"` to look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of lists like this:

```
lists = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],..]
```

Then, if you iterate over it with a for loop, you'll get the individual lists as the items as the items.  The third element is offset 2, and the fourth is 3 (python lists are zero indexed).

```
for li in lists:
    pl.plot(list[2],list[3])
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `list` as a variable name. Don't use it in for loop.

Comment: Second, your codes raise error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'c'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't plot 2 strings but you can plot their indexes like;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

lst1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'],
        ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'],['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3']]

for x in lst1:
    pl.plot([3,4])
    pl.xlabel("{}".format(x[3]))
    pl.ylabel("{}".format(x[4]))
    pl.show()
```

If you run this, you see first `e,d` from `3` to `4`

[image]

If you close it, you'll see other plots `e1,d1` , `e2,d2` and so on.

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
for i in list:
   pl.plot(i[3],i[4])
```

instead of

```
for i in list:
    pl.plot(list[i][3],list[i][4])
```

---

**Solution to your problem:**

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
l=[[1,2,3,4,5],[10,11,12,13,14,15]]
d=[]
e=[]
for i in l:
    d.append(i[3])
    e.append(i[4])
for a,b in zip(d,e):
    pyplot.scatter(a, b)
pyplot.xlabel("d")
pyplot.ylabel("e")
for a,b in zip(d, e): 
    pyplot.text(a, b, (str(a)+","+str(b)))
pyplot.show()
```

Output:
[image: Output]